# How to read this kind of .cvs file (html style content) by Python2.7?

Tags: python, html, pandas, runtime-error

I am practicing *github* machine learning contest using *Python*. I start from other's submission, but stuck at the first step: use pandas to read *CSV* file:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

filename = './facies_vectors.csv'
training_data = pd.read_csv(filename)
print(set(training_data["Well Name"]))
[enter image description here][1]training_data.head()
```

This gave me the following error message:
pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 104, saw 3

I could not understand that the .csv file describe itself as html DOCTYPE. Please help.

The representing segments of the csv data content are attached. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you see the link to the sample data in JPG format? Let me post some

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class=" is-u2f-enabled">
  <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# object: http://ogp.me/ns/object# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article# profile: http://ogp.me/ns/profile#">
    <meta charset='utf-8'>

Comment: <svg aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-mark-github" height="28" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="28"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8c0 3.54 2.29 6.53 5.47 7.59.4.07.55-.17.55-.38 0-.19-.01-.82-.01-1.49-2.01.37-.....2.53-.49-..21.15.46.55.38A8.013 8.013 0 0 0 16 8c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8z"/></svg>
</a>

Comment: </tr>
      <tr id="LC941" class="js-file-line">
        <td id="L941" class="blob-num js-line-number" data-line-number="941"></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>A1 SH</td>
        <td>SHANKLE</td>
        <td>2775.5</td>
        <td>98.41</td>
        <td>0.615</td>
        <td>12.8</td>
        <td>14.105</td>
        <td>3.2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0.968</td>

Comment: I don't understand why it is saved as `.csv`. What happens if you just try and use `pd.read_html`? Also, I would edit your question to get the links in for you but it seems the first one is missing? I'm not quite sure where the image link should be placed in your question based on the stuff you've posted in comments (which should be edited into your answer, not as comments)

Comment: Actually, the stuff contained in the image link that _is_ available (https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3yqt.jpg) could easily be copy/pasted into the question and just use the code formatting that you used on your python code. You shouldn't need to link to any images for this question.

Comment: I do not understand neither, but the pd.read_cvs seems work for other submitters. I tried pd.read_html, it gives the following error:

Comment: ImportError: html5lib not found, please install it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I download the csv file following the convention of regular web operation: right click and save as. The right way is open the item from github, and then open it from the github desktop. I got the tables now. But the way to work with html files from python is definite something I would learn more about. Thanks.